# input with pagebreak

Tags: input

I tried to find an answer on the forum but I could not.

I have some tables in separate files, which I want to organize in a single file. The preamble is the same for all tables. I use:

```
\begin{document}
\input{table1.tex}
\input{table2.tex}
\end{document}
```

The two tables are put into the same page. I tried to add a `\pagebreak` between the first and the second `\input` but it does not work.

Then I tried with `\include`:

```
\begin{document}
\include{table1.tex}
\include{table2.tex}
\end{document}
```

In this case, I try to compile, I do not get any error message but the pdf does not come out.

Any guess on how I could resolve my problem? Thanks in advance.

**ADDENDUM**

The big file containing all the tables is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, makecell, siunitx}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[scale=.75,textheight=27cm, textwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=***, 
table-number-alignment =center}
\newcommand*{\MyIndent}
{\hspace*{1.5cm}}

\begin{document}
\input{table1.tex}
\input{table2.tex}
\end{document}
```

In table1.tex I have the following code (table2.tex is pretty similar with different variables):

```
\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\centering
\normalsize
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Baseline model \label{table3}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
\toprule \toprule
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{POLS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{WG}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Kiviet--WG}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{DIF--GMM}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{SYS-GMM}\\

\midrule \noalign{\medskip}

$(ln)y_{i,t-1}$             &        .984\sym{***}&        .674\sym{***}&        .895\sym{***}&        .519\sym{***}&        .957\sym{***}\\
                    &      (.007)         &      (.043)         &      (.036)         &      (.128)         &      (.013)         \\
$PC$                  &       -.029\sym{**} &       -.045\sym{***}&       -.033\sym{***}&       -.103\sym{***}&       -.107\sym{***}\\
                    &      (.015)         &      (.013)         &      (.013)         &      (.039)         &      (.036)         \\
$PC^{2}$                 &        .003\sym{**} &        .004\sym{***}&        .003\sym{***}&        .010\sym{***}&        .011\sym{***}\\
                    &      (.001)         &      (.001)         &      (.001)         &      (.004)         &      (.003)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &         681         &         681         &         681         &         553         &         681         \\
R$^2$               &        .989         &        .723         &                     &                     &                     \\
F-test              &    5531.466         &      85.460         &                     &                     &                     \\
Log--likelihood     &     401.638         &     621.943         &                     &                     &                     \\
\bottomrule \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
      \item[]{\textit{Notes}: ***, ** and * denote significance at 1\%, 5\% and 10\% level. Geographic and period dummies included but not reported. Robust standard errors in brackets.}
      \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

    enter code here
```

The point is that I cannot insert a `\pagebreak`

If I tried with `\include` I cannot generate a pdf file (I can compiles the tex file with no errors, but the pdf does not come out).

Thanks

Comment: `\clearpage` would help. But you can also put the preamble in the main file `\begin{documen} ...preamble ...` an then you can use `\include{table1.tex} \include{table2.tex}` instead of `\input`. Include is like 1.`\clearpage` and 2.`input{}`  [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250/124842).

Comment: Can you show a minimal version of what you have in `table1.tex`? Note also that `\include` must be used ***without*** the `.tex` extension.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks for your reply. \clearpage works, although it does not center the second table in the page. I tried to use include, but as I said the file can be compiled but the pdf does not come out.

Comment: @egreg. Thanks for your reply. I will edit my previous question including the content of table1.tex

Comment: Maybe you have to delete old files. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, makecell, siunitx}
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[scale=.75,textheight=27cm, textwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=***, 
table-number-alignment =center}
\begin{document}
\include{table1}
\include{table1}
\end{document}` works for me.

Comment: @Bobyandbob. Thanks. I tried exactly the code you have provided. I cancelled all old aux files and other auxiliary files, but still I cannot generate the pdf file, although I do not get any error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `\begin{table}` into `\begin{table}[p]` and using

```
\input{table1}

\clearpage

\input{table2}
```

will solve your problem.